# VBA If Statement in excel

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

He all I need help writing an If statement that will run a macro every time the value in cell D8 is over one.  No idea where to start

Comment: Look at this thread for automatically running code when the value of a cell changes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409434/automatically-execute-an-excel-macro-on-a-cell-change

Comment: Are you sure you need a macro? What do you need it to do if your trigger cell is > 1?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range("D1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Not Range("D1").Value > 1 Then Exit Sub

MsgBox "D1 > 0"

End Sub
```

For more info on the _Change event:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx

Comment: That is not working unfortunatly.  the first If statement is giving me a run time error 424

Comment: 1: Check for typos. 2. Make sure you have put this in the Worksheet's code module, NOT in an ordinary code module.  3. If you still can't get it to work, debug the value of `Target`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple if statement.

```
    If Range("D8").Value > 1 Then
        '~~> Your code here
    End If
```

You can put that in the `Worksheet_Change` event. I would also recommend reading this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640) which talks about `Worksheet_Change`

If the value in `Range("D8")` is changing because of a formula then you might have to use the `_Calculate` event. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406628/vba-code-doesnt-run-when-cell-is-changed-by-a-formula/11409569#11409569) for an example.