# How to use Excel VBA "Worksheet_Calculate" function for a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want my macro to activate ONLY when a calculated cell in a SPECIFIED range changes. At the moment the macro activates whenever any cell on the sheet is calculated.

For example, how would I alter the following code so that `Macro1` only activates when a cell in `Range(A1:A5)` changes due to a calculation, and not when cells in any other ranges are recalculated? Any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Macro1
End Sub
```

Comment: The hack is to create a new, dedicated sheet, containing only a single populated cell, which references your target cell e.g. `=Sheet1!A435+0` - the Calculate event for that new worksheet would necessarily be scoped to your targeted cell

Comment: [This might help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413877/run-vba-script-when-cell-value-change-by-formula)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should do it...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Static last, test
    
    test = [sum(a1:a5)]
    
    If Not IsError(test) Then
        If last <> test Then
            last = test
            Macro1
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You are welcom, Sebastian!