# Timestamp when a cell is changed via a formula (Excel)

Tags: vba, excel

I need a way to timestamp an adjacent cell whose value changes via formula. Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406628/vba-code-doesnt-run-when-cell-is-changed-by-a-formula) as an example I need the cell adjacent to A1 on sheet 1 to timestamp the date and time when the cell value changed.

The example I have linked to above initiates a message box when the cell value changes via formula (worksheet_change events don't appear to recognise changes to a cell value when it contains a formula whose value is changed because of a cell change elsewhere). I don't want the message box but I do want a timestamp.

For simplicity I will post the instructions at that linked question here, any additional help with this specific question is appreciated.

In Sheet1 Cell A1, put this formula

```
=Sheet2!A1+1
```

Now In a module paste this code

```
Public PrevVal As Variant
```

Paste this in the Sheet Code area

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Range("A1").Value <> PrevVal Then
        MsgBox "Value Changed"
        PrevVal = Range("A1").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

And lastly in the ThisWorkbook Code area paste this code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    PrevVal = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `MsgBox "Value Changed"` to:

```
Range("B1").Value = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

or whichever [timestamp format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx) you require

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast reply. That worked perfectly.

Comment: Can this be modified to accommodate a range of cells, say A1:A10?

Comment: @Andy You would need to keep your previous values in an array - it's not very difficult to change the code you currently have, but it's certainly different enough that you should ask a new question. :)

Comment: I've learnt that starting a new question closely related to an existing one is like walking through land mines but I'll take that chance ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186207/timestamp-when-a-cell-in-a-larger-cell-range-is-changed-via-a-formula-excel