# Timestamp when a cell in a larger cell range is changed via a formula (Excel)

Tags: vba, excel

As a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184798/timestamp-when-a-cell-is-changed-via-a-formula-excel/43184855) question, I need a timestamp in an adjacent cell whenever a cell is changed via a formula for a range of cells.

I'm aware this means building an array to store the previous values into the code below (which achieves the same but only for a single cell) and would appreciate any help achieving this.

Here's the code that works for a single cell...

In Sheet1 Cell A1, put this formula

```
=Sheet2!A1+1
```

Now In a module paste this code

```
Public PrevVal As Variant
```

Paste this in the Sheet Code area

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Range("A1").Value <> PrevVal Then
        Range("B1").Value = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
        PrevVal = Range("A1").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

And lastly in the ThisWorkbook Code area paste this code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    PrevVal = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead you can use worksheet_change event to detect change in a sheet (any range of data) and add timestamp in the sane row changed. You may use Target.row to identify the changed row.

Comment: @ArindamD, Worksheet_Change doesn't detect formula changes

Comment: Change to `PrevVal = application.sum(Range("A1:A9").Value)` in both places. Then if any value in A1:A9 changes, the sum of all of the values will change.

Comment: oh, and change to `Range("B1").Value = Now: Range("B1").Numberformat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"`.

Comment: I tried that but while it updated the timestamp in B1 for any change in the range A1:A9, I want a separate timestamp adjacent to every cell that changes.

Comment: @Jeeped, there are plenty of occasions when that wouldn't work. To name a few: if the numeric changes offset each other or if there were non-numeric values. OP also wants to know exactly which values have changed - not just whether or not they've changed.

Comment: @CallumDA - and that is why it was a comment and not posted as a solution. If the OP decides that it is addequate then it is less calculation intensive (and a little easier to follow) than a variant array or scripting dictionary solution.

Comment: @Andy - Sorry, I simply did not infer that from your title or narrative.

Comment: No need to apologise, I can see a usage case for it in other instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep your previous values in a `Dictionary` rather than an array. To use the dictionary you need to add a reference to *Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library*

(Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library)

---

**Standard module**

```
Public PrevVal As Dictionary
```

---

**ThisWorkbook module**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim r As Range
    Set PrevVal = New Dictionary
    For Each r In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
        PrevVal.Add Item:=r.Value, Key:=r.Address
    Next r
End Sub
```

---

**Sheet module**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim v As Variant

    For Each v In PrevVal.Keys()
        If Range(v).Value <> PrevVal(v) Then
            Range(v).Offset(0, 1).Value = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
            PrevVal(v) = Range(v).Value
        End If
    Next v
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice answer - do you need to `Remove` and then `Add` again ?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie thanks - I actually can't test this code because I'm working on a Mac. I had a quick look to see if you can change the value of an item in a Dictionary given its key and didn't come up with anything. Still looking though :)

Comment: Overwriting the keys' item value should be sufficient.

Comment: When I update a cell, I get an error after running Debug it highlights this line in the code - For Each v In PrevVal.Keys()

Comment: @Andy Did you save and close/reopen? because there's nothing in the dictionary until you run the Workbook_Open sub (i.e. when you open your workbook)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't and now I have it works perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: As a followup, can I use this in multiple sheets? Currently it's just for Sheet 1 but what if I want it in Sheet 5 and Sheet 6 as well?

Comment: @Andy, create three public dictionaries and paste the code into each of the sheet modules, change the code to refer to the specific dictionary for that sheet

Comment: Do I create those extra public dictionaries by adding additional modules?

Comment: @Andy, no just three lines in the same module will be fine :)

Comment: So just to clarify, I post Public PrevVal As Dictionary three times in the standard module? What about the This Worksheet part of the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139804/discussion-between-callumda-and-andy).

Comment: Big props to @CallumDA for the help.