# Put timestamp when a checkbox is ticked or unticked

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with 3 rows and 7 columns (`A1:G3`).
A and B columns have 6 checkboxes (`A1:B3`). Boxes in columns A & B are linked to columns C & D respectively. Cells in columns E & F are just replicating columns C & D respectively (live `E1` cell is `=C1` and `F3` cell is `=D3`).

I want to put a timestamp in cell G for each row when a checkbox is ticked or unticked by using Worksheet_Calculate event in VBA for that sheet.

My code works when used for just 1 row.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_calculate()
    Dim cbX1 As Range
    Set cbX1 = Range("A1:F1")
    If Not Intersect(cbX1, Range("A1:F1")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("G1").Value = Now()
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to combine the code for 3 rows.

Here are 2 variations:

1st one:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_calculate()
    Dim cbX1 As Range
    Dim cbX2 As Range
    Dim cbX3 As Range
    Set cbX1 = Range("A1:F1")
    Set cbX2 = Range("A2:F2")
    Set cbX3 = Range("A3:F2")
    If Not Intersect(cbX1, Range("A1:F1")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("G1").Value = Now()
    ElseIf Intersect(cbX2, Range("A2:F2")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("G2").Value = Now()
    ElseIf Intersect(cbX3, Range("A3:F3")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("G3").Value = Now()
    End If
End Sub
```

When I combine them with `ElseIf` like in the code above, a timestamp gets put in only `G1`, no matter if I tick `B1` or `C2`.

2nd one:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_calculate()
    Dim cbX1 As Range
    Dim cbX2 As Range
    Dim cbX3 As Range
    Set cbX1 = Range("A1:F1")
    If Not Intersect(cbX1, Range("A1:F1")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("G1").Value = Now()
    End If
    Set cbX2 = Range("A2:F2")
    If Not Intersect(cbX2, Range("A2:F2")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("G2").Value = Now()
    End If
    Set cbX3 = Range("A3:F2")
    If Not Intersect(cbX3, Range("A3:F3")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("G3").Value = Now()
    End If
End Sub
```

When I combine them by ending each one with `End If` and start a new `If`, timestamp gets put in all of the `G1`, `G2` and `G3` cells, even if I tick just one of the boxes.

Comment: Worksheet Change or Worksheet Calculate?  Also, `If Not Intersect(cbX1, Range("A1:F1")) Is Nothing` will always be true, since `cbX1` is the same as `Range("A1:F1")`, and similarly for the rest of the conditions.

Comment: @BigBen thanks for your quick reply. Worksheet Calculate since both - "the cells linked to checkboxes" and "the cells that replicate previous cells" are considered as a formula type. Worksheet change will only work if it's changed manually. Cells get TRUE and FALSE values based on formula.

Comment: Right, I was just commenting that you mention "Worksheet_Change" in your question....

Comment: @BigBen oh, sorry, I think I just wrote my question too quick and made a mistake. Edited my question

Comment: Maybe see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406628/vba-code-doesnt-run-when-cell-is-changed-by-a-formula), as well as this [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184798/timestamp-when-a-cell-is-changed-via-a-formula-excel) of it.

Comment: @BigBen I've tried that solution, but for some reason I don't get timestamp update when I untick the checkbox. It gets updated only when I tick it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be confusing Worksheet_Calculate with Worksheet_Change and using Intersect as if one of the arguments was Target (which Worksheet_Calculate does not have).

`Intersect(cbX1, Range("A1:F1"))` is **always** not nothing because you are comparing six apples to the same six apples. You might as well ask *'Is 1,2,3,4,5,6 the same as 1,2,3,4,5,6?'*.

You need a method of recording the values of your range of formulas from one calculation cycle to the next. Some use a public variable declared outside the Worksheet_calculate sub procedure; personally I prefer a Static variant array declared within the Worksheet_calculate sub.

The problem with these is initial values but this can be accomplished since workbooks undergo a calculation cycle when opened. However, it is not going to register Now in column G the first time you run through a calculation cycle; you already have the workbook open when you paste in the code and it needs one calculation cycle to 'seed' the array containing the previous calculation cycle's values.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Static vals As Variant

    If IsEmpty(vals) Then   'could also be IsArray(vals)
        vals = Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(3, "F")).Value2
    Else
        Dim i As Long, j As Long
        With Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(3, "F"))
            For i = LBound(vals, 1) To UBound(vals, 1)
                For j = LBound(vals, 2) To UBound(vals, 2)
                    If .Cells(i, j).Value2 <> vals(i, j) Then
                        Application.EnableEvents = False
                        .Cells(i, "G") = Now
                        Application.EnableEvents = True
                        vals(i, j) = .Cells(i, j).Value2
                    End If
                Next j
            Next i
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. I not only works perfectly, but also opened my eyes to realize that I was on a wrong way. Good luck

Comment: Please note that I added disabling the events with                             Application.EnableEvents = False so that writing the timestamp did not trigger Worksheet_Change (if you had one of those).