# How to start two VBA Macros at once when different trigger cells are changed via formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on an Excel-Sheet that mostly uses standard formula in cells but has two main VBA macros. These macros need to get triggered by three different cells that **change their value automatically by formula**.

Imagine it like this:

- 3 pairs of cells spreaded over the sheet (1 pair = 1 trigger cell + 1 output cell)
- 1 calculating macro and 1 cleaning macro
- If one trigger cell changes to "x", the calculating macro starts and gives an output to the nearby output cell.
- While this happens, the other trigger cells go to "" what starts the cleaning (ClearContents) of their output cells.
- I thought about cleaning the output cells not needed within the calculation of the needed one, but there is a possibility that all 3 trigger cells go to "". Because of this, I tried to realize the cleaning in a separate macro to avoid having the last output remaining all the time.

I'm working with Excel 2010 on Windows 7 and this is my code so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
'controls if trigger cell values change
'calls macros with trigger parameters

    Select Case target.Address

        'Trigger 1 activated
        Case "$A$1"
            With target

                If .Value = "x" Then
                    Call Calculation(1)     'calculate output cell 1
                ElseIf .Value = "" Then
                    Call Clean(1)           'clean output cell 1
                Else
                    Call Error              'error notification
                End If

            End With

        '-------------------------------------------

        'Trigger 2 activated
        Case "$A$2"
            With target

                If .Value = "x" Then
                    Call Calculation(2)     'calculate output cell 2
                ElseIf .Value = "" Then
                    Call Clean(2)           'clean output cell 2
                Else
                    Call Error              'error notification
                End If

            End With

        '-------------------------------------------

        'Trigger 3 activated
        Case "$A$3"
            With target

                If .Value = "x" Then
                    Call Calculation(3)     'calculate output cell 3
                ElseIf .Value = "" Then
                    Call Clean(3)           'clean output cell 3
                Else
                    Call Error              'error notification
                End If

            End With


    End Select

End Sub
__________________________________________________________________________

Sub Calculation(Trigger As Integer)
    'calculation process with detection which output is to fill
End Sub

__________________________________________________________________________

Sub Clean(Trigger_Clean As Integer)
    'cleaning process with detection which output is to clean    
End Sub

__________________________________________________________________________

Sub Error()
    'individual error notification
End Sub
```

While using my code, I noticed, that it works fine for manually changed trigger cell values (wrote x and pressed Enter) but not for a value change by formula. I also noticed that I'm not able to trigger the calculation of output 1 and the cleaning of output 2 and 3 or the cleaning of all output cells at once.

**What I need to know:**
How to get the macros started by automatic trigger cell value changes and how to start the calculation and the cleaning processes at once or in a row?

It really hope my problem finds your interest.
Thank you for any help in advance.

RaspiManu

Comment: You need to look at the `Worksheet_Calculate` event

Comment: Thank you very much for that hint. Searching through Stackoverflow with this in mind brought me to a solution. I will post an answer with the helpful thread and my finished code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the hint of Luuklag, I found a solution by Siddharth Rout in this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406628/vba-code-doesnt-run-when-cell-is-changed-by-a-formula?noredirect=1&lq=1).

I optimized it for my needs to get the following codes:

in a module:

```
Public PrevVal_1, PrevVal_2, PrevVal_3 As Variant
```

in `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    PrevVal_1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    PrevVal_2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
    PrevVal_3 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value

End Sub
```

in `Sheet1`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    If Range("A1").Value <> PrevVal_1 Then

        If Range("A1").Value = "x" Then
            Call Calculation(1)        
        ElseIf Range("A1").Value = "" Then
            Call Clean(1)                         
        Else
            Call Error                              
        End If

        PrevVal_1 = Range("A1").Value

    End If

    '-------------------------------------------

    If Range("A2").Value <> PrevVal_2 Then

        If Range("A2").Value = "x" Then
            Call Calculation(2)        
        ElseIf Range("A2").Value = "" Then
            Call Clean(2)                         
        Else
            Call Error                             
        End If

        PrevVal_2 = Range("A2").Value

    End If

    '-------------------------------------------

    If Range("A3").Value <> PrevVal_3 Then

        If Range("A3").Value = "x" Then
            Call Calculation(3)        
        ElseIf Range("A3").Value = "" Then
            Call Clean(3)                          
        Else
            Call Error                              
        End If

        PrevVal_3 = Range("A3").Value

    End If


End Sub
```

I really hope this helps someone with a similar problem.

RaspiManu