# Do not update linked Excel cell based on a timestamp

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

First question: two Excel cells are linked (A6 = A3). When I update A3, A6 gets updated.

How can I register to the change event of A6?

By using the following VBA code, I register to the change event of A3, but I cannot find how to register for the automatic change of A6.

1. Any idea how to do this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("A14:A15"))_
            Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."
    End If
End Sub
```

Here's the broader scenario that I am trying to achieve: Depending of the value of a timestamp, I would like the second cell to update itself, or keep its current value.

Here's the current behavior. A6 and A7 reference A3. If I update A3 to "2", A6 and A7 gets updated to "2" as well. Regardless what the timestamp says (the C column just contains the formula used in the B column, for explanation purpose):

[image: Example1]

What I would like to achieve is the following.

[image: Example2]

The timestamp B6 is one minute in the past and B7 one minute in the future. After updating A3 to "2", I want A6 to remain "1", and B7 to update itself to "2".

In order to do this, I thought I can use the change event described above and block the update event after I tested the timestamps in a macro.

2. Any better idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Answer to your first question: changed formula outputs are not recognized as `Change` events, however you can catch them through the `Calculate` event. Have alook [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11409569/9758194)

Comment: As you now know, the `Change` event is not triggered by a formula update.  *If* my understanding of **Volatile Functions** is correct, then you can create a **Volatile UDF** that will achieve your goals.  Please understand I have not tested to confirm my understanding is accurate, let alone suitable for your purpose, but I do believe it is worth exploring.

Comment: Instead of using formulas to update your child values, you could get around this issue altogether by updating your child values with VBA instead. You could trigger this with a `change` event.