# Date doesn’t auto fill when the cell updates data automatically but manually when I change data it works well

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet Change (ByVal Target As Range)
Dim MyDataRng Às Range
Set MyDataRng = Range ("A2:A10")
If Intersect (Target, MyDataRng) Is Tawning Then Exit sub
On Error Resume Next
If Target.Offset (0, 1)
• Then
Target.Offset (0, 1) = Now
End If
Target.Offset (0, 2) = Now
```

I was trying to get auto filled date and time to my worksheet. When I enter anything within the added columns it works fine. But when the sheet auto fills from the other linked sheets it doesn’t update. I manually have to enter it. WHY?

Comment: Is your code _exactly_ as you posted here, or have you modified it for posting here?

Comment: Er, Tawning O_O?

Comment: Changes in cell values due to formulas do not trigger the `Worksheet_Change` event.  You have to use the Calculate event instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406628/vba-code-doesnt-run-when-cell-is-changed-by-a-formula

Comment: Could you share the formula in `A2`?

Comment: @VBasic2008 I actually couldn't get done what i exactly wanted so I used this formula instead =IF(C3<>"",IF(D3="",NOW(),D3),"") but it doesn't work the way I want it.

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim MyDataRng As Range
Set MyDataRng = Range("G2:G58")

If Intersect(Target, MyDataRng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

On Error Resume Next
If Target.Offset(0, 1) = "" Then
    Target.Offset(0, 1) = Now
End If

Target.Offset(0, 2) = Now

End Sub       @chrisneilsen

Comment: Is there any solution that you know of? @TimWilliams

Comment: You can use the `Worksheet_calculate` event but I can't follow your logic for when a date needs to be added.

Answer (score -1):

IMHO, if you set the concrete range like
`Set MyDataRng = Range ("A2:A10")`
Why are you using  "Offset" function except of setting the value you need to column B in concrete cell?

```
Dim a As Long
a=Target.Row
Cells(a,2)= Now
```

or just so

```
Cells(Target.Row,2)= Now
```

Offset is used when you have dynamic source range. And when you have exact Target range, you can write an offset address from Target